# setting parent div to flex but not getting child components to render as such

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hi Everyone I am currently working on a React project and my main issue is the fact that I can not seem to get the child elements of a div - which in this case are imported components - to render as flex.

Is there a different approach to this sort of thing in React compared to the traditional way or am I doing something wrong?

The results are the divs being dislayed as block elements, with a 30% width, instead of being floated side by side.

My code is shown below;

JSX:

```
<div ClassName="selectClientContainer">
  <SelectClient />
  <SelectClient />
  <SelectClient />
  <SelectClient />
  <SelectClient />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selectClientContainer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.selectClient {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.selectClient img {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the default flex direction in react is `column`. Change it to `flex-direction: row`

Comment: ^The default `flex-direction` in normal HTML/CSS is in fact `row` and I expect the same in react.js, why would it be any different there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have capitalised the C when assigning a `className` so it remains undetected. Change it to `<div className="selectClientContainer">` and it will work.